# Explain Build.scala in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

Can somebody explain the syntax for Build.scala in detail?  For example, I have the following `Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object Build extends sbt.Build {

   val appName         = "myapp"
   val appVersion      = "1.0"

   val appDependencies = Seq(
      "postgresql"    %   "postgresql"        % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
      javaCore,
      javaJdbc,
      javaEbean,
      "org.json"      %"org.json"             % "chargebee-1.0",
      "org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.8",
      "org.mockito"   %   "mockito-all"       % "1.9.5" % "test"
    )

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
      libraryDependencies += "com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0-rc2-SNAPSHOT",
      resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-snapshots", new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
      resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    )

}
```

How do I match the `appDependencies` with the `resolvers`? Or how do I know what `resolvers` I need to add for what `appDependencies`? Where do I look in the resolver's repo? What is `libraryDependencies`? How are they different from `appDependencies`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things we need to disentangle here.

Let's first distinguish between an *sbt* build file and `Build.scala`. While the build file is exactly like a Maven pom or a Gradle build file, think of `Build.scala` as a build capability with the full power and expressiveness of Scala because it is a Scala class like any other. I believe the gap between the two has narrowed though with the latest version of *sbt*.

Now in both *sbt* and `Build.scala`, you have the notion of [library dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html), which are the jar libraries containing code you can use for your projects. These libraries can be found in lots of places--Maven repositories, the local file system, etc. You use [resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers.html) to specify those locations.

So you tell both which jars you need and where to find them.

As for `appDependencies`, that's not actually a thing. As I said, `Build.scala` is a class like any other, and `appDependencies` is just a variable name. It just makes sense to use that name because that `Seq` is what you will pass to the `Project` constructor.